# Provisioning Vagrant with mySQL (on MacBook Pro M2)

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, vagrant, apple-silicon

#### Background

Around 2 years ago I set up a `vagrant/ubuntu` web development environment on my MacBook Pro (Intel). That worked well enough that it had been set & forget until I upgraded to an M2 MBP. It works as documented [here](https://github.com/p2made/p2vagrant), up to installing PHP.

Then I add...

```
config.vm.provision :shell, path: "provision/scripts/mysql.sh", :args => [MYSQL_VERSION, RT_PASSWORD, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME, DB_NAME_TEST]
```

to my `Vagrantfile`, which runs...

```
#!/bin/bash

# MYSQL_VERSION    $1
# RT_PASSWORD      $2
# DB_USERNAME      $3
# DB_PASSWORD      $4
# DB_NAME          $5
# DB_NAME_TEST     $6

# Install MySQL
apt-get update
apt-get -y upgrade

debconf-set-selections <<< "mysql-server mysql-server/root_password password $2"
debconf-set-selections <<< "mysql-server mysql-server/root_password_again password $2"

apt-get -y install mysql-server

# Create the database and grant privileges
CMD="sudo mysql -uroot -p$2 -e"

$CMD "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS $5"
$CMD "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON $5.* TO '$3'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '$4';"
$CMD "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS $6"
$CMD "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON $6.* TO '$3'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '$4';"
$CMD "FLUSH PRIVILEGES;"

sed -i "s/.*bind-address.*/bind-address = 0.0.0.0/" /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
grep -q "^sql_mode" /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf || echo "sql_mode = STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION" >> /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf

service mysql restart
```

That script is exactly as used both in the earlier version of my GitHub project, & my production environment. It now fails with...

```
: ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IDENTIFIED BY 'Pa$$w0rdTw0'' at line 1
: ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IDENTIFIED BY 'Pa$$w0rdTw0'' at line 1
: Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
```

If I reduce `mysql.sh` to (effectively)...

```
#!/bin/bash

#RT_PASSWORD     = $2

# Install MySQL
apt-get update

debconf-set-selections <<< "mysql-server mysql-server/root_password password $2"
debconf-set-selections <<< "mysql-server mysql-server/root_password_again password $2"

apt-get -y install mysql-server

service mysql restart
```

It runs without error. Given the lack of error, I take it the intended root password on MySQL was successfully set.

So I try `ssh` into Vagrant to create the database...

```
vagrant ssh
sudo mysql -uroot -pPa$$w0rd0ne -e "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS 'db'"
```

It fails with a different error...

```
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Running the `sed` line in `ssh` produces no error, however running the `grep` line produces error...

```
-bash: /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf: Permission denied
```

#### Question

What must I do to make my `mysql.sh` script work again?

Comment: Are you moving from 5.7 to 8.0? Implicit user creation in GRANT statements has been removed. You need to `CREATE USER ...` and then `GRANT ...`

Comment: @user1191247 On checking, it turns out I am. And now I'm off to try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because implicit user creation in GRANT statements is no longer available in MySQL 8.0, you need to create the user first:

```
$CMD "CREATE USER '$3'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '$4';"
$CMD "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS $5"
$CMD "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON $5.* TO '$3'@'%'"
$CMD "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS $6"
$CMD "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON $6.* TO '$3'@'%'"
```